# Google Chart API QR Code don't work

Tags: google-visualization, qr-code

I try to generate a QR code with the Chart API. This works but when I try to read the QR code it doesn't recognize the text. When I try to read other QR codes it works fine. Here is the test URL: https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=qr&chs=150x150&ch1=Test

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The final parameter name is chl not ch1.